# How to write an XML file from an XSD cxx tree object?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xerces-c, codesynthesis

I am working with a library that uses XSD for creating objects from their XML-based format in C++.

Basically, the inheritance diagram looks something like this:

```
class BaseClass: public xsd::cxx::tree::type;
class MainXmlObject: public BaseClass;
```

I think I need to convert my `MainXmlObject` to a `xerces::DOMDocument` and then use `DOMWriter` to write the actual XML file, but I couldn't find the right routines so far.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like adding the `--add-serialization` flag to the xsd code generation and then using something like:

```
xml_schema::namespace_infomap map;
//    map[""].name = "test"; // xmlns
//    map[""].schema = "http://sbgn.org/libsbgn/0.2"; // xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
ofstream ofs(fname.c_str());
sbgn_(ofs, s, map); // invoking the stream here
ofs.close();
```

works. References: [Adding serialization](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/cxx/tree/guide/#2.5) and [details](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/cxx/tree/guide/#6) from the [XSD guide](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/cxx/tree/guide/).